# Rails Complex Database Relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design

I am working on a project which consists of Schools, Students and Articles. As I started developing my Articles controller I realized that there had to be a better way to accomplish my goal, but I just don't have the experience to figure it out. Basically what I am trying to do is have my Users register to a certain school. Then once the user logs in, he should be able to see all articles from his school and by category. Here is my setup, any advice would be appreciated:

school.rb:

```
class School < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  has_many :articles, :through => :users
  attr_accessible :name
end
```

user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :articles
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :provider, :uid, :school_id
end
```

category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :articles
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles
end
```

article.rb:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Does this seem like a good setup to accomplish my goal? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What's the connection between users and articles? Do users create articles, or just read them (or both)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While everything looks pretty good, I'd suggest linking articles directly to schools as well as users. So you'd end up with something like:

```
# school.rb
has_many :users
has_many :articles

# user.rb:
belongs_to :school
has_many :articles

# category.rb:
has_many :articles

# article.rb:
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :school
```

Linking articles directly to schools make more sense from a modelling point of view. At the moment, your structure says that an article belongs to the school its user currently belongs to; while that may generally work, it's an extra point of fragility that you could end up paying for in the long run.

Given it sounds like one of the main activities will be for users to browse articles for their school, it also complicates the process by which your app will load these articles. With your current structure, it would take the following steps:

1. Find the current user's school.
2. Find every user belonging to that school.
3. Find every article written by each of those users.

Linking articles directly to the school would cut out that 2nd step, which would give you a free increase in performance, especially if you get to large numbers of users and articles.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I will fix everything in the morning, and start testing it out. I will also remove the accepts_nested_attributes, as @Ajcodez suggested. Now that you mentioned it, everything makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The `accepts_nested_attributes_for :articles` feels like a mistake. Besides that looks fine to me, assuming users are creating articles.

I think there are a few questions you need to consider with user's articles. What happens to the articles if a user...

- deletes his/her account
- transfers schools
- graduates school completely

Perhaps for these reasons, schools should have articles straight out and not through users. But depends on how you want it to work.

---

You may also want to reconsider the 1-to-many relationship with a category and articles. Often its easier to use a tags system with a many-to-many relationship between pieces of work and categories.

Imagine if the article is about the return of wind power for freight shipping. It could belong in both the International Business and the Technology categories.

---

Write some tests for how you want the classes to work, and let that guide your design specifics.

Comment: Thank you! Your feedback as well as Zaid's were very helpful, I really appreciate it.